# Local solvability and Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem for PDEs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, cauchy-problem

I am trying to understand the exact implications between local solvability and a general version of the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya (CK) theorem, in the context of PDEs.

Let $\Delta(x,u^{(n)})=0$ be a system of PDEs of order $n$. Here $x$ is the vector of independent variables, and $u^{(n)}$ is the vector of dependent variables and all their derivatives up to order $n$. According to Olver ("Applications of Lie groups to Differential Equations", 2/e, Ch. 2, Def. 2.70), $\Delta$ is *locally solvable* if the variety it induces on $\mathbb{R}^{|x|+|u^{(n)}|}$

$V(\Delta):=\{(x_0,u_0^{(n)}):\Delta(x_0,u_0^{(n)})=0\}$

coincides with its solution variety

$S(\Delta):={\small \{(x_0,u_0^{(n)})\in V(\Delta) : \text{ $\exists$ an analytic solution $U$ of $\Delta$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$
s.t. }  U^{(n)}(x_0)=u_0^{(n)} \}}$

Olver shows that if $\Delta$ is in Kovalevskaya form then it is locally solvable (Corollary 2.74, p. 163; this is indeed an easy consequence of CK theorem). He then states that the same result still holds when $\Delta$ is in *general* Kovalevskaya form:

[image]

I am struggling to convince myself of the validity of this statement. For instance, consider the 2nd order system $\Delta$ in the independent variables $t,x$ and the dependent variables $u,v$:
\begin{align*}
u_t & = v\\
v_{tt} &= u_x\,.
\end{align*}
From what I gather, this system is not locally solvable. Indeed,  there are differential consequencences that are not captured algebraically by the two equations above, such as $u_{tx}=v_x$. So there are points $(x_0,u_0^{(2)})\in V(\Delta)$ s.t. (with obvious notation) $u_{0,tx}\neq v_{0,x}$, hence not in $S(\Delta)$.

Yet, $\Delta$ is in general Kovalevskaya form, is it?

Edit:  for reference, I paste Olver's original definition. Note that $pr^{(n)}f$ denotes the $n$-th prolongation of $f$.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you find all solutions by solving the first order system \begin{align*}
  u_t &= v\\
  v_t &= w\\
  w_t &= u_x
\end{align*}
with initial data $(u,v,w)$ along $t = 0$?

Comment: Your system is "equivalent" to the old one in terms of solutions. However the point here is not finding the solutions, but solving the apparent contradiction I have pointed out. Cheers

Comment: Why is this system not locally solvable? Doesn’t $u_{0,tx} = v_{0,x}$ follow from the assumption that the equations hold at $(x_0,t_0)$ up to second order.

Comment: This is in the definitiion of $S(\Delta)$, but not in that of $V(\Delta)$. That is, there are 2nd order differential consequences (e.g. $u_{tx}=v_x$) that are *not* algebraic consequences.

Comment: Here, it appears that local solvability means that any second order jet that solves the system can be extended to a local smooth solution (which is not the standard definition of local solvability). To be a second order solution, the three equations *and* the first partial derivatives with respect to both $x$ and $t$ of the first two equations must hold. In particular, if a 2-jet is a solution at $(x_0,t_0)$, $u_{tx} = v_x$ then holds at $(x_0,t_0)$. So in fact this equation is a consequence of the jet being in $S(\Delta)$.

Comment: It may not be the 'standard definition' of local solvability, but it is the way it is defined Olver's textbook. I copy it below:

Comment: I have pasted the original definition into my question. In short, for l.s. we require $V(\Delta)=S(\Delta)$ on the 2nd order jet, which does not seem to be the case for my 2-equations system. Of course it is the case for your 3-equations system, but this does not solve my doubt about Olver's statement.

Comment: I would second Deane's comment that Olver's defnition is not the most common/reasonable one. In fact, it reads a little "lazy," which surprises me. Here's a better definition. _Locally solvable_: every formal power series solution (aka an $\infty$-jet at a point) is the Taylor series of a smooth solution (locally extends to a smooth solution). Dropping this definition into your example removes any contradictions. Note that the extended Kovalevskaya form precisely guarantees a unique formal solution for any free initial data (of appropriate order for $u$ and $v$).

Comment: @Igor. Ok, so to be specific, you propose to replace the definition of $S(\Delta)$ given in my question with $S(\Delta):=...$? As an aside, concerning the extended Kovalevskaya form, my understanding is that it additionally guarantees analiticity (given analytic initial data). If one is interested in formal power series solutions, disregarding analyticity, there are more generous formats. See e.g. here [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717103000178?via%3Dihub).

Comment: @Michele To be specific, replace $V(\Delta)$ by the locus of $\infty$-jets cut out by $\Delta=0$ and all of its differential consequences, at the same time replace $S(\Delta)$ by the locus of $\infty$-jets of locally defined smooth/analytic (as you prefer) solutions. Then $S(\Delta) = V(\Delta)$ is a good definition of local solvability. Sure the ext-K form gives you lots of information, but also including the ability to specify formal solutions by finite amounts of data (the free initial data), as I wrote earlier. The hypotheses of the Cartan-Khäler theorem do that in even more generality.

Comment: @Igor. This fills the gap between $S(\Delta)$ and $V(\Delta)$, at the cost of forcing infinite jets in the definition of $V(\Delta)$, thus spoiling its finitary, 'algebraic' nature. For instance, suppose $\Delta$ is polynomial, then it may be useful to reason on $V(\Delta)$ in algebraic-geometric terms, that is as the affine variety induced by $\Delta$ on $n$-th order jets. Note that local solvability (Olver style) is central also in differential-completion algorithms for PDEs, like Cartan-Kuranishi: see e.g. p. 15 [link] (https://www.maths.dundee.ac.uk/plin/SiAM_ReidLinWittkopf_01.pdf ).

Comment: @Michele There is no argument against both subjective and temporal fluctuations in what is or is not a good definition. There are many ways in which a definition may be modified to suit one's taste. Is that the philosophical direction you intended your question to go in? The gap between $\infty$-jets and finite order data is closed by the notion of an _involutive form_ of a PDE, about which many volumes have been written. Your last reference is an example. Another notable reference is _Involution_ by W. Seiler (Springer, 2010).

Comment: @Igor. Just to clarify, my direction is merely pragmatical. In particular, again restricting to the polynomial case, being able to use certain well-known algebraic-geometric notions (notably, Groebner bases) for algorithmic purposes. Just to make a simple example, under suitable conditions, the set of invariant polynomials of $\Delta$ --- those identically 0 on solutions of $\Delta$ --- coincide with the ideal generated by $\Delta$, on $n$-order jets. This in turn may be useful in direct methods to search for conservation laws.

Comment: @Michele There is no reason to be hypothetical. All of the tools that you have mentioned are in fact already being used in the relevant literature, without any compunctions about using $\infty$-jets when convenient. This discussion seems to be veering more into philosophy. I'm not sure what other practical information I could add, besides what I already wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The system you wrote down
First, let's assume everything is smooth.
\begin{align*}
  u_t &= v\\
  v_{tt} &= u_x\\
\end{align*}
is equivalent to the first order system
\begin{align*}
  u_t &= v\\
  v_t &= w\\
  w_t &= u_x
\end{align*}
in the sense that $(u,v)$ is a solution to the first system if and only if $(u,v,w)$ is a solution to the second system, where we set $w = v_t$.

By Cauchy-Kovalevski, given any analytic functions $u_0(x), v_0(x), w_0(x)$, there exists a unique analytic solution $(u,v,w)$ to the second system such that $u(x,0) = u_0(x), v(x,0) = v_0(x), w(x,0) = w_0(x)$. This is equivalent to saying that given any analytic functions $u_0, v_0, w_0$, there exists a unique analytic solution $(u,v)$ to the first system such that $u(x,0) = u_0(x)$, $v(x,0) = v_0(x)$, and $v_t(x,0) = w(x)$, which is what Olver asserts. The fact that $u_{tx} = v_x$ is a consequence of the equations and need not be specified in the initial data.

As for Olver's definition of local solvability, an element of $V(\Delta)$ for the original system consists of a $2$-jet $(x_0,t_0,u(x_0,t_0), u_x(x_0,t_0), u_t(x_0,t_0), v(x_0,t_0), v_x(x_0,t_0), v_t(x_0,t_0))$ that satisfies the system up to second order. On other words, at $(x_0,t_0)$,
\begin{align*}
u_t &= v\\
u_{tx} &= v_x\\
u_{tt} &= v_t\\
v_{tt} &= u_x
\end{align*}
In particular, if a $2$-jet lies in $V(\Delta)$, then $u_{tx} = v_x$ does hold for that $2$-jet at $(x_0,t_0)$. Given such a $2$-jet, you can extend $u$, $v$, and $v_t$ arbitrarily to initial data along $t = 0$ and solve the system as described above. In particular, the initial data is *assumed* to satisfy $u_{tx} = v_x$ at $(x_0,t_0)$.